# Passthrough touches of 2 UIScrollViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, touches

I have 2 descendants of `UIScrollView`

I have a `UITableView` which displays data
and i have a `UICollectionView` added above the `UITableView`

```
view  
 | - UITableView
 | - UICollectionView
```

The `UITableView` can only scroll vertically and the `UICollectionView` can only scroll horizontally. I can only scroll my tableview where the `collectionview` isn't overlapping (which is off course expected behaviour) but i need to make it so that i can scroll my `tableview` even if i swipe vertically on my `collectionview`.

I cannot simply add the `collectionview` as a subview of the `tableview` because of other reasons (which i know, would make this work)

Is there any other possibility to let de touches from the `collectionview` passthrough to the `tableview`?

Comment: Hi are you there?
you need to place the MAin view contain 2 sub views and first one's subview is table view and second one's subview is collection view then only it will work

Comment: scroll view directly added as the subview of the tableview then it will not work scroll will miss behave

Comment: An screenshot of what you're trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, you want touches to be intercepted by UITableView as well as UICollectionView?

I think You can try resending touch events from your UICollectionView to UITableView.
(manually calling touchesBegin, touchesMoved, touchesEnded, etc.)

Maybe overriding touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded methods will work for your case.

You can try overriding UICollectionView with your subclass (with property set to your UITableView instance) and implementing touch handling methods with something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.tableView.frame, [touch locationInView:self.tableView.superview]) {
       [self.tableView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

        [self.tableView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

        [self.tableView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

        [self.tableView touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

Hope it will help, however I'm not 100% sure about it.

I've found this article also, maybe it will be useful

http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-trick-for-capturing-all-touch-input-for-the-duration-of-a-touch/

Answer (score 4):

You can try to create a subclass of `UICollectionView` and add this code to your `CustomCollectionView`'s .m file.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return hitView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add pan gesture recognizer with direction vertical on collectionview. On the vertical pan event, you can change the content offset of your table view to scroll it.

Comment: but than you don't have bounce effect out of the box.